# Replace part of a line of text in a file in a shell script

Tags: shell

Please let me know how to replace a **some text in a line** with another text....

Example:

- text to be replaced - `/test/India/Mark/`,
- new entry - `/testing/Aus/Markos/legacy`

Using the `sed` command, I am not able to do it as `/` is used in the syntax itself, like `sed 's/old text/new text/g'`.

How can it be done?

Answer (score 2):

This should help

Some people use colons:

```
sed 's:/test/India/Mark:/testing/Aus/Markos/legacy:' <old >new
```

Others use the "|" character.

```
sed 's/test/India/Mark|/testing/Aus/Markos/legacy|' <old >new
```

Comment: Getting error on using this, sed: Function 's/test/India/Mark|/testing/Aus/Markos/legacy|' cannot be parsed. Please help

Comment: Make sure that you're using quotes and not slashes

Answer (score 0):

#### Original answer

<sup>*Appropriate when the question emphasized 'whole line'.*</sup>

Use a different character, such as `@`, to delimit the search/replace commands, and use `\@` to specify a context search:

```
sed -e '\@^/test/India/Mark/$@ s@@/testing/Aus/Markos/legacy@'
```

The space in the command text is optional and present for clarity.  You could probably also do:

```
sed -e 's@^/test/India/Mark/$@/testing/Aus/Markos/legacy@'
```

with essentially the same effect.  The main difference is that the context search would allow you to group multiple actions together, rather than just doing a single substitution, so it is more general.

Note that the only requirement was that `@` does not appear in the search pattern or replacement text.  You can use any character; sometimes, a control character such as <kbd>Control-A</kbd> is effective.

#### Update

Since the question has been modified to emphasize part of a line rather than a whole line, the commands to use change correspondingly, but the basic technique (use different delimiters) remains the same.  Specifically, the start-of-line and end-of-line anchors are no longer appropriate:

```
sed -e 's@/test/India/Mark/@/testing/Aus/Markos/legacy@'
```

Note that this uses exactly the strings in the question, but if there was some text such as 'XVIII' after the slash after `Mark`, then the replacement has `legacyXVIII` rather than `legacy/XVIII`.  We cannot tell whether that matters; we only have the information in the question to work with.

Comment: Thanks a lot...let me give it a shot

Comment: Will it work if there are some text before and after /test/India/Mark??

Comment: No (it will not work if there is some text before and after `/test/India/Mark`), because I put `^` and `$` in the pattern to look for the exact line.  Remove the `^` and `$` if the pattern can appear anywhere in the line.  You then need to decide whether you want to replace just what matches or the whole line.  Your question asked about a line to be replaced, which I interpreted as meaning "the whole line".  But it is easy to adapt to changed requirements; the technique of using an alternative character to delimit searches and substitute commands is general.

Comment: So the one one I have to use is........ sed -e 's@/test/India/Mark/@/testing/Aus/Markos....is that correc?

Comment: You could use `sed -e 's@/test/India/Mark/@/testing/Aus/Markos/legacy@` and it will replace the string `/test/India/Mark/` with `/testing/Aus/Markos/legacy`.  If that gets the result you want, great.  If you want a different result, then you need to be more precise about what you do want.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, worked like a charm :) ....                                         sed -e 's@/test/India/Mark/@/testing/Aus/Markos/legacy@'